Did the command that God gave Hosea to marry a prostitute have anything to do with illustrating a deeper spiritual lesson?
When the Lord first spoke through Hosea, the Lord said to Hosea, "Go, take to yourself a wife of whoredom and have children of whoredom, for the land commits great whoredom by forsaking the Lord." Hosea 1:2
I’m not sure if I worded the question correctly, but what I’m asking is how exactly does this command help or illustrate anything? If nothing happened or changed because of it, why was Hosea condemned to have this fate or his innocent daughter who didn’t do or know anything be condemned to have a name that means not loved? I know that names/ their meanings are important in the Bible.
Gomer conceived again and gave birth to a daughter. Then the LORD said to Hosea, “Call her Lo-Ruhamah (which means “not loved”), for I will no longer show love to Israel, that I should at all forgive them.
( some other versions say “no mercy”…not sure which one it really is)
I’ve looked for answers but all of the answers are the same: And the Lord said to me, “Go again, love a woman who is loved by another man and is an adulteress, even as the Lord loves the children of Israel…
God wanted to provide an illustration of His relationship with the people of Israel…
Again, what was this helpful for?

It is well-known that Jesus told many parables (Matt 13:10-13, 34, 22:1, Mark 3:23, 4:2, 33, 12:1, etc).  Similarly, there are many OT parables.  However, there was also a Jewish tradition of enacted parables.  Here is a sample:

The siege of Jerusalem acted out, Eze 4
Ezekiel's razor and sword and his shaved head, Eze 5
Israel's exile acted out, Eze 12
Judah's doom acted out with a cooking pot, Eze 24
The two sticks, Eze 37:15-28
Jeremiah's Linen Loincloth, Jer 13
The entire book of Hosea is an enacted parable of unfaithful Israel
Jesus cursing of the fig tree is an enacted parable, Mark 11:12-14
Jesus washing the disciple's feet is an enacted parable. John 13
Belt of Agabus, Acts 21:10-12
The iron horns of Zedekiah, 1 Kings 22:11

Thus, the experience of Hosea and Gomer was an enacted teaching parable to teach about God's forgiveness of erring Israel.  That is:

Hosea represented God willing to persist with an erring wife/nation
Gomer represented Israel.
Gomer's unfaithfulness represented Israel's repeated propensity to sin against God by lusting after other husbands/gods.  For other examples of this common metaphor, Isa 47:1-3, Jer 2:32, Eze 16, Nah 3:4, 5


Thank you. Although it’s the same response  that I found in most other articles. It’s an illustration of how Gods relationship was with the people of Israel. In this case you used the words enacted parable rather than illustration. I wanted to know that since nothing happened because of it, why the people involved were doomed to these fates/ why the daughter had to live with a name meaning not loved. I guess there’s really no good answer. But I really appreciate your response.

Those closest to God share God's experience. Hosea, standing in the position of God's representative to the people of his generation, took up the burden of loving a woman seemingly unworthy of his love. God led him to this course because God was in a similar position, loving his "wife" Israel despite her infidelity. God suffered because of Israel's faithlessness, and by marrying a wife who would not be faithful, Hosea showed God's "steadfast love" for his people. In so doing, Hosea also demonstrated his own attitude of complete obedience to God.
The OP asks: "What was this helpful for?" This is what @Dottard called an "enacted parable," but it was enacted as a most profound level. It provided an deeply moving example of God's love, a love which will ultimately prevail no matter what. Thus God promises Israel through the prophet:

“And it shall be at that day,” saith the Lord, “that thou
shalt call Me ‘Ishi’ [that is, My husband], and shalt call Me no more
‘Baali’ [that is, My Lord]. (Hosea 2:16)

This prophecy has a double meaning: Israel will turn away from the baals, and she will also no longer relate to God as a lord or master (based on law), but as a husband (based on love). The ultimate purpose of Hosea's course is to provide a dramatic example of redemption. As Hosea's unconditional love for his wife will eventually redeem her, so God will redeem his wayward people.
Lo-Ruhamah
About the tragic name  given to Hosea's daughter (Lo-Ruhamah, meaning "not loved" or "not pitied") I would make two points: First, tragic names are more common than one might think. Ainsley means "alone." Claudia means "crippled." Dolores mean "pains/sorrow." Miriam and Mary are related to "bitterness." Secondly, we should consider that many OT figures had both a symbolic name and a common name. Although the prophet Nathan named David's second son Jedediah, he is known to history as Solomon. Although an angel told Joseph that his son would be known as Emmanuel, in everyday life he was called Jesus. Therefore, Lo-Ruhamah would not necessarily what her parents normally called her. Indeed, in the next chapter, God is quoted as saying:

I will sow her for myself in the land,
and I will have pity on Not-Pitied. I will say to Not-My-People, “You are my people,”
and he will say, “My God!”

Thus, God gave these negative symbolic names to show that his love would prevail absolutely. He expected Gomer and Hosea to show  unconditional love to their children. In so doing they undoubtedly had the freedom to give them pet names for everyday use that would demonstrate that they were were indeed loved and accepted by their parents. If God can "have pity on Not Pitied" then her parents can lovingly play with he name as well. I like to picture them calling her simply "Ruhamah" ("mercy") or perhaps shortened version of this word as a nickname. One might think of a Dolores (literally "sorrows" in Spanish) being called Dolly or Lola.
Conclusion: God asked Hosea to walk a suffering path to bring him closer to God's heart and show the people of Israel an example of his absolute love for them. The tragic names given to the prophet's children were not meant to be permanent and were probably not used for them in everyday life.

Thank you! @Dan Fefferman
